# Using the Python multiprocessing library and non-daemonic, nested processes, how can I detect the halting/death of a parent process?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing

Here is my skeletal architecture (note it does not contain the spawning/killing of persistent child threads within the `DataComputation` `run()` method):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection
from loguru import logger
import psutil

class DataComputation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasking_pipe = mp.Pipe()

    # Return tasking pipe endpoint for main process to use
    def get_tasking_pipe_parent(self) -> Connection:
        pipe_child, pipe_parent = self.tasking_pipe
        return pipe_parent

    # Supporting calculation function for run()
    def do_calculation(data):
        return data(...)

    # Main operation function
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Deconstruct Tasking Pipe
        current_pipe_end, external_pipe_end = self.tasking_pipe
        # Run until kill instruction received
        while True:
            # Receive tasking data; Break if kill instruction received
            tasking_data = external_pipe_end.recv()
            if tasking_data == None: break
            # Do something meaningful with tasking data
            process = mp.Process(target = do_calculation, args=(tasking_data))
            processed_data = process.start()
            # Send processed data to main Algorithm
            current_pipe_end.send(processed_data)

    # NON-GRACEFUL FAILSAFE: Thread that watches for parent death; kills siblings on event
    def watcher_thread(self, siblings_list) -> None:
        while True:
            parent_process = psutil.Process(os.getppid())
            if parent_process.status != psutil.STATUS_RUNNING: # *****THIS DOES NOT WORK******
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        # Invoke kill threads function with 'None' as process_list to trigger built in exception
        self.kill_threads(siblings_list)

    # Kill all threads in supplied process list via None message sent through process queue
    def kill_threads(self, process_list) -> None:
        # Attempt graceful, thread suicide via call to process pipe
        pipe_parent = self.get_tasking_pipe_parent()
        for process in process_list:
            pipe_parent.send(None)

        # Await threads to terminate
        for process in process_list:
            process.join()


class MainAlgorithm:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create Data Computation class instance; store communication pipe for tasking
        self.data_computation_class = DataComputation()
        self.tasking_pipe = self.data_computation_class.get_tasking_pipe_parent()

    def run(self):
        # Create Data Computation class "run" process; Provides "API" calls through tasking pipe
        data_comp_run_process = mp.Process(target=self.data_computation_class.run, args=())
        data_comp_run_process.daemon = False
        process_list = [data_comp_run_process]

        # Spawn watcher thread to kill data_comp_run_process in case of non-graceful MainAlgorithm shutdown
        data_comp_watcher = mp.Process(target=self.data_computation_class.watcher_thread, args=([process_list]))
        data_comp_watcher.daemon = False
        data_comp_watcher.start()

        # Start Data Computation class "run" process
        for process in process_list:
            process.start()

        # Do something meaningful
        return_data = 0
        for int in range(10):
            self.tasking_pipe.send(int)
            return_data += self.tasking_pipe.recv()

        # OH NO SYNTAX ERROR AND MAIN PROCESS HALT
        x = None
        y = x + 1
        # ^^^^^^^ PROGRAM STOPS ^^^^^^^ HOW DO I DETECT THIS IN THE CHILD WATCHER THREAD AND KILL THE CHILDREN THREADS

        # Gracefully kill Data Computation class "run" process and subsequently kill watcher process
        self.tasking_pipe.send(None)
        for process in process_list:
            process.join()
        data_comp_watcher.terminate()
        data_comp_watcher.join()

        return return_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    alg_instance = MainAlgorithm()
    data = alg_instance.run()
```

The issue is that I must use nested processes for this purpose, and thus, use non-daemonic processes. This means, child threads aren't automatically reaped upon graceful/non-graceful main-process termination. Additionally, the solution needs to be Docker Container friendly.

Any help, whatsoever, would be incredibly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: making multiprocessing code bulletproof is a lengthy process, with lots of ways to accomplish what you're going for. I'd start with a once-over of [this](https://www.cloudcity.io/blog/2019/02/27/things-i-wish-they-told-me-about-multiprocessing-in-python/) article, with particular attention to "always handle signals", "never wait forever", and "always clean up after yourself". My best advice would be to make the main process bulletproof, and shift anything that might crash to another process. Flat is better than nested wherever possible.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for the link! Definitely had some eye-opening insights I'll incorporate into my design.